# Can Visual Studio Code use Emmet completion in razor .cshtml files

Tags: razor, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm using Visual Studio Code (1.17.1, on MacOS 10.13 AND Windows 10) developing an asp.net core mvc web app using razor templating.
Visual Studio Code supports Emmet (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

My issue is that Emmet works correctly in HTML files, but will not work in razor CSHTML files.

I've found:

> To enable the Emmet abbreviation expansion in file types where it is not available by default, use the emmet.includeLanguages setting. Make sure to use language ids for both sides of the mapping.
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

but it doesn't indicate where to find a list of "language ids". I tried searching for it, but you can imagine what happens when you search for programming language id!

Is there a way to tell Emmet in VS Code to treat cshtml files as html files? Is there any other way to get this to work (besides renaming the files, which is another solution out there)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), the corresponding language for *.cshtml files is *razor*, thus you need to specify it in the **emmet mappings** as follows:

`"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "razor": "html"
}`

Comment: Glad it helped you

Comment: Thank you so much @Aegis, i was trying to set a wrong config:

```

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "cshtml": "html"
}

```
=/

Now it works great!

Comment: @WilliamHowley you can use the WebEssentials extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: This appears to be broken in version 1.17.0 of the OmniSharp plug-in, but you can restore full functionality by disabling that plugin. You can restore partial functionality by changing `"razor": "html"` to `"aspnetcorerazor": "html"`.

Comment: @Chris The actual answer did not work for me, but yours did, thanks!

Comment: Clarification: Disabling the OmniSharp plug-in makes `"razor": "html"` work. If you keep the plug-in, you can have some functionality with `"aspnetcorerazor": "html"`. If you find yourself toggling the plugin, you don't have to keep changing the setting. You can have both active: `"razor": "html","aspnetcorerazor": "html"`

Comment: is it possible for Visual Studio IDE? (not VS code)

Comment: I had to enable `"razor.devmode": true` along with `"aspnetcorerazor": "html"`

Comment: @Brad So, you have the C# Extension activated, and in your settings `"razor.devmode": true` and `"aspnetcorerazor": "html"`inside `"emmet.includeLanguages"`  to make formatting works ?

Comment: {
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "aspnetcorerazor": "html",
    },
    "razor.devmode": true,
}

Yes, C# extension is active. `C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).`

Comment: With that config, when I try formatting, I go 
`There is no formatter for 'aspnetcorerazor'-files installed.`

Answer (score 13):

updated:
**Press Ctrl+K than M (Ctrl+K,M) than select highlighter from the dropdownlist you want** this is a common shortcut. very useful. even works for any file types. ie. create a new file and code some xml or what language you want than Ctrl+K,M you can specify/override ide hilighter on the fly. very useful shortcut. try it. you won't forget Ctrl+K,M. one of most useful hotkey combination I ever use in vscode. by this way code-completion wakes up and works as language you selected.

in vscode > settings.json 
I added the related codes mentionel above. emmet worked for cshtml files.

```
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
   "razor":"html",
   "aspnetcorerazor":"html"
  }
```

Comment: This "aspnetcorerazor":"html" is needed for Blazor

Comment: also needed "aspnetcorerazor":"html" for .NET 6.0.

Comment: For Blazor netcoreapp3.1 it was required to add aspnetcorerazor to get proper support. A handy gist is here, which also shows example for react : 
https://gist.github.com/stormwild/2e870b0823bba98950de15fe8dd00f9a