# Visual studio code: how to automatically change the matching closing tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code when changing the start tag type (e.g., from `<div>` to `<span>`) I want the editor to automatically change the matching closing tag. How can I do that?

Comment: There is vscode extension that will solve your problem.

Comment: Most probably this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982436/12069171

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this thread from the first result of Google SERP, see Neil's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70353463/8604951 since VSCode supports the functionality by default right now. No need to install another plugin & bloat your system lol.

Comment: The feature request _Mirror Cursor for JSX_ is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51832).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Start VS Code, go to Plugins and search for Auto Rename Tag. Install, reload, done. This plugin:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag

Comment: This plugin is very broken. Would not recommend. Any other solutions appreciated

Comment: Since v1.41, it is built in https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-rename-tags

Comment: @JamesMulholland most of the time it works pretty good..

Comment: As of Jan 2022, It's no longer called plugins, but rather view > extensions.

Comment: @timiscoding Sadly doesn't work for PHP files.

Comment: THIS made it work

Comment: Specify languages using the [VSCode language ids](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers). `"auto-rename-tag.activationOnLanguage": ["typescriptreact"]` for _.tsx_ files (in the settings.json).

Answer (score 117):

Since VSCode 1.44, you can enable automatic updating of matching tags like this:

1. Go to File menu, Preferences and Settings
2. Search for `editor.linkedEditing`
3. Enable "Linked Editing"

[image: Screenshot of Linked Editing setting]

Here is an example of how it works:

[image: Example of linked editing]

Comment: I've enabled it but it still doesn't link the edition... I had to press F2 to change..

Comment: It works on .html files but does not work on React .jsx files. The Auto Rename Tag extension from the accepted answer does work on both.

Comment: support for JSX is added in VS Code 1.79. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_linked-editing-for-jsx-tags (cc @VIBrunazo)

Comment: Thanks! Working great with `.vue`. IMO it should be enabled by default

Comment: @KacperWyczawski It should. And it should be named something else so it's more intuitive to find. Something with "tag", "sync" or "html"...

Comment: Works great with `.svelte` files ... thanks!

Answer (score 50):

You can use the [Rename Symbol command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring) to do this.

1. Select (or click to put the caret anywhere inside) the opening tag
2. Hit <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Enter the new tag name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Opening and closing tags will both be renamed.

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at step 3 to preview changes and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to apply them.

Comment: This will rename the import statement of the component with `OldName as NewName`... :(
Ctrl+D is probably the best option.

Comment: One disadvantage of F2 is you cannot use it to set an empty tag. If you delete the name and press Enter, then it will cancel the operation.

Comment: In JSX, F2 just shows "Cannot be renamed" for me. The `Emmet: Update Tag` code action works though

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned by @TwistedSim, you can achieve this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: This is what the VS Docs say to use.

Comment: Well, unless there's matching text between the tags. Then some text in the middle gets highlighted also.

Answer (score 5):

`F2` works in (js|jsx).

If you happen to have IntelliJ Keybindings installed you can achieve the same with `SHIFT + F6`.

`CNTRL+D` didn't work for me at all. I'm on a Mac at the moment.

Comment: CMD+D for Mac...

Answer (score 3):

From [Anders Carstensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492977/anders-carstensen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69863056/6309)

> It works on `.html` files but does not work on React `.jsx` files.
> The Auto Rename Tag extension from the accepted answer does work on both

Actually, VSCode 1.78 (Apr. 2023) will support tag rename for `.jsx`/`.tsx` files.
See [issue 159534](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159534) and [PR 179806](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/179806), available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).
It requires TS 5.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Enable linked editing from settings. See screenshot:

[image: settings]