# How to disable VS Code auto-rename-tag / HTML mirror feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to be able to easily edit HTML tags together. It seemed to me like this is such an easy thing to implement nowadays, so I've installed this [auto-rename-tag extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag), and it turned out to be not useful for me: instead of helping me in html/jsx code editing, it breaks everything and I have to undo what it does and try to edit the thing to avoid triggering it.

The logical thing here would obviously be to remove this extension from my system. The only problem here, however, is that I can't seem to do that - I've uninstalled it, even reinstalled VS Code, tried VS Code Insiders, but here it is, still enabled:

[image: in action]

Is it built-in now? How do I disable it?

VSCode version: 1.41.0, commit 9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959

Comment: HTML Rename tags is a different feature from the mirror cursor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628833/select-matching-element-rename-html-tag-in-visual-studio-code/59221721#59221721

Comment: Yes, the HTML Rename is a different feature. But the HTML Mirror Cursor is similar to the functionality provided by the [Auto Rename Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) extension, which edits both start and end HTML tags if you place your cursor on them.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It has become a built-in feature, separate from the Auto Rename Tag extension. If you don't like it, you can disable it depending on which version you've got installed.

---

## Update for 1.52+

The setting has now been renamed to **Linked Editing**:

> The **On Type Rename** feature for editing a tag when its matching
> closing tag is modified is now called **linked editing**. The command
> to enable linked editing is **Start Linked Editing** (⇧⌘F2) and Escape
> disables linked editing mode.
>
> The setting to enable/disable it is now:
>
> ```
> "editor.linkedEditing": true
> ```

Or from the UI:

[image: Settings > Linked Editing]

---

## Update for 1.44+

They changed the mirror cursor feature and are now calling it [Synced Regions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_synced-regions).

[image]
<sub>*(copied from the VS Code 1.44 release notes)*</sub>

When activated on HTML tags, if both start and end tags become "synced", then changing one also changes the other. The feature is disabled by default though, and either you explicitly execute the **On Type Rename Symbol** command or set the `editor.renameOnType` setting to true.

With this change, the `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` introduced in 1.41 will now show up as deprecated (or grayed-out).

[image]

---

## Update for 1.42+

The `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` is now disabled by default starting in [1.42](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_html-mirror-cursor-off-by-default).
See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60064641/2745495) for the quotation from the release notes.

---

## Original Answer for 1.41

It's now a built-in feature starting 1.41.

**HTML mirror cursor**
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-mirror-cursor

> VS Code now adds a "mirror cursor" when you are editing HTML tags.
> This behavior is controlled by the setting
> `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag`, which is on by default.
>
> This feature works by adding a [multi-cursor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor) to the matching tag when
> your cursor moves into an HTML tag name range. Just like in
> multi-cursor mode, you can use word-wise deletion or word-wise
> selection. The mirrored cursor is removed when you move your cursor
> outside the tag name range.

Basically, selecting either the tag start or the tag end puts 2 cursors on each, so editing one also edits the other. It is enabled by default.

You can explicitly disable it from your settings.

Via UI:

[image]

Via settings.json:

```
"html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag": false,
```

Comment: I found this feature is very buggy and corrupt HTML on copy/paste operations. I leave this comment here because Code developers prevent to create Issues on their site :(

P.S.
It seems html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag = false helps

Comment: This feature is incredibly buggy, arbitrarily changing content in other tags and deleting large swathes of content when I edit tag attributes. It should never have gone out in this state. Things like this risk ruining a good editor, when they start bloating it with half-baked and ill-tested features when it was working fine before.

Comment: I agree with KoViMa and @Garret Wilson that implementing this feature by default calls into question the judgement of the Code dev team. Expess yourself about it at this MS monitored thread: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87737

Comment: @VanAlbert, thanks; I have [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87737#issuecomment-573046065) on the issue.

Comment: Does this work with `.vue` files or any other custom file types that have HTML/XML in it? Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Jack Are you referring to the Synced Regions feature or the Auto Rename Tag extension? For VS Code's Synced Regions, it works well on my .vue files, with `editor.renameOnType` set to `true`. With the Auto Rename Tag, try checking the `auto-rename-tag.activationOnLanguage` setting. Other than that, I don't know, the issue here was actually how to turn it off.

Comment: @GinoMempin The auto rename tag extension works.  I got a pop up saying VSCode supports tag renames now so uninstalled the extension and set renameOnType to true but it didn&#39;t work.  Is the new vscode setting supposed to replace the third party extension?

Comment: @Jack OK, on my env, I still have the Auto Rename Tag installed, and I think that's why I thought it was working for .vue files. Yes, it does not seem to work on its own, and I don't know about the goals for this feature. I think it's best you ask a *separate question*, because my answer and the question itself is about *turning this feature off*, rather than making it work.

Comment: none of the above works, it is called Linked Editing now https://roboleary.net/vscode/2020/08/05/dont-need-extensions.html

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#html-mirror-cursor-off-by-default  with v1.42 due out early February, 2020.

> **HTML Mirror Cursor off by default**
>
> We have made Mirror Cursor an opt-in feature. In the upcoming
>   iteration, we'll continue to improve its implementation to make this
>   feature more easily understandable and available to more languages.
>   You can still use this feature by turning on
>   `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag`.

-----   Update March 2020  ----------

The vscode devs have heard you.  The mirror cursor functionality is being substantially modified.  You can test it in the Insiders' Build now so perhaps it'll get into v1.44 or soon thereafter.

Especially pasting into a tag has been much improved.  And no dual cursors.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88424#issuecomment-600840619

And release notes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#synced-regions It is in v1.44.