# How to disable multiple caret selection for html element in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I edit html in VS Code, it has started to behave differently than before. When I select an html-element, a caret appears on the closing element as well (see gif). How do I disable this "feature"
[image]

Comment: look in the updates 1.38+. Or in the settings for "multi", has been asked here a few days ago but can't find the question

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I figured it out

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628833/select-matching-element-rename-html-tag-in-visual-studio-code/59221721#59221721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of rioV8, I was able to figure it out. Seems like is was an update in [November 2019, version 1.41](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-mirror-cursor) , and I found the settings in VS Code (see image).

I had to disable an option (Mirror Cursor On Matching Tag) that was enabled by default

[image]